# How can I put a faded and jagged border around an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put borders around images so that it looks like the image below. Is it possible in CSS?[image]

Comment: Just curious, Why does it have an upvote? Eventhough it shows no effort!

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Because someone with no clue upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible with CSS. Use PNG image with cutoff for real image and place it above real image

```css
.border {
  background: url("http://www.clker.com/cliparts/b/W/3/l/3/I/gold-cool-border-hi.png") no-repeat center center;
  width: 504px;
  height: 593px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 504px;
  height: 593px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/510/600/" />
  <div class="border">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this `class` `css` to your style sheet

```
.border_gradient {
border: 8px solid #000;
-moz-border-bottom-colors:#897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
-moz-border-top-colors:#897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
-moz-border-left-colors:#897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
-moz-border-right-colors:#897048 #917953 #a18a66 #b6a488 #c5b59b #d4c5ae #e2d6c4 #eae1d2;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 15px;
width: 300px;
}
```

set `width` to the `width` of your image. and use this `html` for image

```
<div class="border_gradient">
        <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

though it may not give the same exact border, it will some gradient looks on the border.

source: [CSS3 Borders](http://designshack.net/tutorials/introduction-to-css3-part-2-borders)

Comment: is there anyway to make this work for chrome as well

Comment: i was also looking forward to that, let's see if i can get to it.

Answer (score -1):

Not with css.

But you could make some images with the jagged border and put html elements around the image. Assign the border images as background to the html elements and put them with position: absolute to the right place.

Watch out for the z-index.

Like this e.g.

```
<div class="div_container"> 
  <img src="some_image.png" />
  <span class="corner--topleft"></span>
  <span class="corner--topright"></span>
  <span class="corner--bottomrright"></span>
  <span class="corner--bottomleft"></span>
  <span class="frame--left"></span>
  <span class="frame--rright"></span>
  <span class="frame--top"></span>
  <span class="frame--bottom"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is a terrible idea!

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Its like the solution from Justinas. Additional bonus is, that it works for unknown image sizes. So its mory dynamic.

Answer (score -1):

You can use images in your border using the border-image properties:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp